# How to get status of web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How can I get the status of web service using C#? whether it is completed successfully, failed or pending like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i found this question [Web Service For Database/Website Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027764/web-service-for-database-website-status)

And you should try this code;

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("myService");
return sc.Status
```

And you should examine this code;

```
public static string PingHost(string args)  
        {  
            HttpWebResponse res = null;  

            try 
            {  
                // Create a request to the passed URI.  
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(args);  
                req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;  

                // Get the response object.  
                res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();  

                return "Service Up";  
            }  
            catch (Exception e)  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Source : " + e.Source, "Exception Source", MessageBoxButtons.OK);  
                MessageBox.Show("Message : " + e.Message, "Exception Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);  
                return "Host Unavailable";  
            }  
        }
```

And also you should look;

[Using Session State in a Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service.aspx)

Comment: i tried your solution but it is giving exception- service 'myservice' was not found on computer 'computername'.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var url = "servicsURL";

        try
        {
            var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "password","domain");
            // Associate the 'NetworkCredential' object with the 'WebRequest' object.
            myRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //  it's at least in some way responsive
                //  but may be internally broken
                //  as you could find out if you called one of the methods for real
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Available", url));
            }
            else
            {
                //  well, at least it returned...
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Returned, but with status: {1}", url, response.StatusDescription));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  not available at all, for some reason
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} unavailable: {1}", url, ex.Message));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling your webservice in sync mode, there is no problem with getting status.

if you are calling your webservice in Async mode, you should set a callback function and track webservice status in the result returned to that callback function.