# How to get status of web services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to get status of web service using the Logic given in this link
[webservice status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631029/how-to-get-status-of-web-service).

```
try
        {
            var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "password","domain");
            // Associate the 'NetworkCredential' object with the 'WebRequest' object.
            myRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //  it's at least in some way responsive
                //  but may be internally broken
                //  as you could find out if you called one of the methods for real
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Available", url));
            }
            else
            {
                //  well, at least it returned...
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Returned, but with status: {1}", url, response.StatusDescription));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  not available at all, for some reason
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} unavailable: {1}", url, ex.Message));
        }
```

But the problem i am facing is, that the code goes to exception block when the service returns  a HTTPStatus code other than 200.

If i have list of say 10 web services and if i am running a foreach loop and executing this code for every URL, and for some reason of my 3rd/4th service returns 500, code goes in to exception block and returns and error.

please suggest on how i can overcome this.

Thanks

Comment: Are services that return 500 errors accessible during the time of execution?

Comment: Yes, when i run try to execute the code i am getting 500 errors

Comment: For the services that give 500 errors, could you check if you can get a response for these services through IE/Soap UI?

I assume these services could be down, hence the app gives 500 errors.

Comment: download Soap UI software and try